# Scattered indices in MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I'm trying to divide up an array between processors such that each one takes points from different parts in the array. For example, if

```
A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```

and I'm using 2 processors, I want P<sub>1</sub> to handle `{1, 3, 5, 7}`, and P<sub>2</sub> to handle `{2, 4, 6, 8}`.

When scaling up to very large numbers of points (millions) and processors (128), this is tricky. In previous versions of my function, I simply gave P<sub>1</sub> the first chunk of points, P<sub>2</sub> the next chunk, and so on (which is easy with `MPI_gatherv`).

Is there some way to use `MPI_gatherv` to make this work, or a way to use `MPI_send` and `MPI_receive` to achieve it? The trouble with `MPI_gatherv` is that while you can specify indices for processors to send to, it still puts all of P<sub>1</sub> before P<sub>2</sub> before P<sub>3</sub> etc.

Comment: Can you post your current code where you are sending the chunks to the processors?

Comment: This -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483360/mpi-sending-segments-of-an-array -- is probably the answer you are looking for.